# How to choose what css file to be imported using next.js?

Tags: html, css, typescript, next.js

I'm now trying to choose which css file to apply using next.js.

I have two css files, one for pc, and one for mobile.

Currently, I am importing css file like below:

```
// _app.tsx

import "../styles/globals.css";  // pc styling css
// import "../styles/globals_mobile.css";  // mobile styling css

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  // ... remaining code
}
```

Now I have mobile css styling file, and I have `isMobile` boolean variable which identifies that the device is pc or mobile from `AppProps`.

But I couldn't find a way how to import css file dynamically.

The below is pseudocode, it is not actually working:

```
// _app.tsx

import pcStyling from "../styles/globals.css";  // it is NOT actually imported.
import mobileStyling from "../styles/globals_mobile.css";  // it is NOT actually imported.


function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  if (pageProps.isMobile) apply mobileStyling;
  else apply pcStyling;

  // ...
}
```

Is there an option I am able to choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your styles are static, you can put them inside the [`public`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving) folder.
And inject the proper link to them inside [`<Head>`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/head) component.

This should look similar to this:

```js
// _app.tsx
import Head from 'next/head';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href={`/styles/globals${pageProps.isMobile ? '_mobile' : ''}.css`} />
      </Head>
      {'rest of your components'}
    </>
  );
}
```

The code above assumes that inside `public` folder there is `/styles/globals.css` & `/styles/globals_mobile.css` files

Comment: I could have managed this thing with your advice! Thanks a lot!